# GET request is not working to retrieve data from the db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I am quite new to node.js and I am writing a GET request to retrieve documents from my database. Here is the definition of my request (in `users.js`) -

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    Booking.find({} ,(err,prevBookings)=>{
      if(err) {
          res.status(400).send('No previous bookings found.');
      }
      if(prevBookings[0]) {
          res.status(200).send(prevBookings);
      }
      else{
          console.log("no records")
          res.status(200).send("No previous bookings found.")
      }
    });

});
```

And I have defined these in the `index.js` file as follows:

```
router.use('/users', require('./users'))
router.use('/prev', require('./users'))
//and there are other routers here too but totally unrelated to users.js
```

But, I am getting the following error on Postman:

`NotFoundError: Not Found`

I know that this error indicates that I am not routing it correctly. But I am not able to identify where I am going wrong. Other routes that I have defined, are working. Could anyone please help me out with this? Thank you :)

Comment: Are you `use`-ing the router in your app? Maybe you prefixed it with something?

Comment: What else is in users.js? I can't see where you're creating the router!

Comment: @TerryLennox Hi, I have edited the question, please check :)

Comment: @ninesalt Hi, no, I have called ````use```` correctly, as far as I can see

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're specifying '/prev' twice. If you change your route in users.js to "/", see what happens. I think at the moment the route "/prev/prev" will return a result.

I'm guessing your users.js should look  like so:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    Booking.find({} ,(err,prevBookings)=>{
    if(err) {
        res.status(400).send('No previous bookingd found.');
    }
    if(prevBookings[0]) {
        res.status(200).send(prevBookings);
    }
    else{
        console.log("no records")
        res.status(200).send("No previous bookings found.")
    }
    });

});

module.exports = router;
```

And then at the top level (index.js) or whatever:

```
app.use("/", router);
router.use('/prev', require('./users'))
```

This should return the correct result on "/prev"

For the booking model, could you try modifying the mongoose schema like so (adding the { collection: } entry):

```
var bookingSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id : {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true
    },
    user_id : {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    places_id : {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Place',
        required: true
    },
    fromDate : {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    toDate : {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    people_count : {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    package_details : {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
    },
    total_cost : {
        type : Number,
        required : true
    },
    cost : {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    // confirmation: {
    //     type : String,
    //     required: true
    // },
    transaction_no : {
        type : String,
        required : true
    }
}, { 
    collection: 'booking' 
}
)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for you help. the /prev/prev thing worked - however, it is telling me that no bookings are found, but I do have bookings in my database. I have also edited the question with the full code from ````users.js````.

Comment: Ok, cool! You're getting nearer to a solution. I'm just wondering if there is something in the Booking model that needs changing. I bet it's something subtle, that a small change will fix.

Comment: Could you show some of the ../models/booking code? I think the find is not returning anything because of a small issue there!

Comment: I have edited the question and added the booking model :)

Comment: What is the table called in the database, is it "Booking", "booking", "user" etc.? I think this is the issue!

Comment: its called booking, all lowercase

Comment: Cool, so if you could add the { collection: 'booking'} entry to the schema as above and give it a try. Fingers crossed!